# An apparently unconventional significance indicator

Tags: statistical-significance, normal-distribution

The following is a statistic used by a water quality consultancy in assessing contaminant concentrations over time:

quality indicator $= \exp(\text{mean}(\ln C_i)+2\,\text{SD}(\ln C_i))$

where $C_i$ is $i$th concentration and $\text{SD}$ is standard deviation

The consultants don't provide the formulation: the reader is left to extract it from their description of the indicator as "the mean plus two standard deviations calculated using log transformed data collected during the baseline period".

The indicator is calculated over a ‘baseline’ period and then subsequent increases in concentration are gauged against this statistic to assess whether a significant change has occurred.

As far as I can tell this doesn’t correspond to a recognised/conventional statistic providing a measure of deviation from a mean (e.g. in the sense of $\text{mean}(\ln C_i)+2\,\text{SD}(\ln C_i)$.

As I read it the quality indicator $= \exp(\text{mean}(C_i))\exp(2\, \text{SD}(\ln C_i))$.

My question is, does it matter?

I should add that the baseline data is close to Normal and applying the log transform results in a slightly more ‘distorted’ distribution.

So it is unclear why they don't simply use $\text{mean}(C_i)+2\,\text{SD}(C_i)$.

Answer (score 3):

If we assume that concentrations are reasonably close to lognormally distributed, so the log is reasonably close to normally distributed, mean + 2 sd is approximately an upper end of a 95% prediction interval (for a future observation) or approximately the limit of a 97.5% one tailed prediction interval.

In particular, if this is being used as a one-tailed test (an observation outside the prediction limit leads us to reject the hypothesis that the new observation comes from the same distribution as that of the data used to generate the prediction limit, it's (notionally) an approximate 2.5% test.

[We can consider this either as approximating 1.96 by 2 in a large sample test or as approximating the corresponding t-critical value; in both cases assuming the sample size is so large that the width of the prediction interval is almost entirely due to the sample standard deviation. Various assumptions are required for this to hold, but it's doubtful several of them will]

However, all that aside, it sounds like there's a *sequence* of such tests to be performed, which changes things from that interpretation; arguably we get into sequential testing.

Comment: Thanks Glen, the figs here give a sense of Nomality/Lognormality:

Comment: Take 2: The figs here give a sense of the data Nomality/Lognormality:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3R3T77A_lr-X2tWSFhocGlsR2M/view?usp=sharing

The mean is obtained the conventional mean of the log transformed data, for data over the baseline period. Likewise the standard deviation. The indicator is obtained as twice the standard deviation of the log transformed data added to the mean of the log transformed data and that summation is then ‘back transformed’ as the antilog. Subsequent data are compared against this 'performance indicator'.

Comment: The "SD" in this case is probably the SD of historical data, not the SD of a statistic.  As such this is a form of (ill-justified) *prediction limit* rather than a confidence limit.

Comment: @whuber Yes, you must be right, I'm sure that's going to be the case; I'll amend.

Comment: The ‘reference’ SD is obtained for/from the baseline/historical data and incorporated into the performance indicator.  Subsequent measurements are periodically (annually) assessed against the performance indicator to determine if a significant increase, relative to the baseline data, has occurred over the assessment period. 
A motivation/justification for the use/invention of the performance indicator isn’t provided; it’s presented as ‘a given’. Seems to me an odd way to test for significant change wrt to the historical data, but as mentioned, my knowledge of statistics is limited.

Comment: @Peter Oh, it's an odd thing to do for several reasons and my description of the possible motivation is a guess; I can't know what was in someone's mind from a formula.

Comment: @Glen_b Found the following  BMJ note “Transformations, means, and confidence intervals”, which, if I read it correctly, suggests their performance indicator isn’t physically meaningful: 
http://www.bmj.com/content/312/7038/1079

Comment: @Peter I believe that there's some mistaken ideas in that link.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for your comments, they've helped clarify things.